# Cannot find module node.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04

I created a new folder on my desktop and in that folder I put a file named app.js containing the following code.

```
function sayHello(name) {
    console.log("Hello" + name);
}

sayHello("Noah")
```

In the terminal I entered node app.js and was returned the following.

```
module.js:549
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/noah/app.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

I followed a Digital Ocean tutorial to get everything installed and everything worked as described. Am I putting my files in the wrong location?

Comment: To run `node app.js` command, you should be in the same folder  where app.js is present. Use `ls` command to check if `app.js` file is present under the folder.

Comment: You should `cd` into folder on desktop that contain `app.js`.

Comment: Thanks I am relatively new to Ubuntu, but that was my issue.

Answer (score 2):

try this in your terminal

```
$ cd /home/noah
$ node app.js
```

or second option

```
$ node /home/noah/app.js
```

I prefer the first option. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder that contains your app.js file and click right mouse button + SHIFT. Then select 'Open command window here' inorder to open your terminal.

In the terminal check your node and npm versions to make sure both are installed correctly in your computer

```
    $ node -v
    $ npm -v
```

Then

```
    $ npm install
```

to download and install necessary node modules to your app.

Finally try,

```
    $ node app
```

or

```
    $ node app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the wrong directory. Using the desktop on Ubuntu was my problem, I will need to figure out how to store and create my files in the user directory to save myself from using cd frequently.